# Can i binding tableview's datasource to my viewModel

Tags: ios, tableview, datasource, viewmodel

Most ViewController has a tableview,and the datasource is too big.
 Can i move the datasource into viewModel because the viewModel also has the model that cell need.

Comment: Yes you can split that. You can make and model as your datasource or delegate.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if I understand you clearly. You wish to set the tableView's dataSource to a class which is different than its ViewController, right?

You can do this. First, ensure your class conforms to the protocol UITableViewDataSource. Someting like this:

```
// In Swift
class MyView: UIView, UITableViewDataSource {
}


// In Objective C, in myview.h
@interface MyView: UIView <UITableViewDataSource>
```

Then, at some point where you initialize your view controller set explicitely your tableView datasource to an instance of MyView. Something like

```
// In Swift
let myView = MyView()
override func viewDidLoad() {
    tableView.dataSource = myView
}

// In Objective C
@interface ViewController()
@property (strong, nonatomic) MyView *myView;
@end


@implementation ViewController
- (void)viewDidLoad() {
    myView = [[MyView alloc] init];
    tableView.dataSource = myView;
}
@end
```

Comment: Most tableView's dataSource should have a Model.Should i assign "MyView" a Model?

Comment: @GodCard, yes you should. I left MyView empty on my code example but you should add its properties and outlets and implement the DataSource and Delegate protocol methods.